# Mobile website mistakenly double-counts users who've earned a given badge more than once

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web

Some of the badges can be awarded multiple times to a same user, badges like Great Question, Great Answer, Famous Question etc.,

In the badge page, we can see how many times the badge was awarded to the users. There is a discrepancy in the text between the desktop and mobile-web view.

For example in [Socratic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) badge page, in desktop view we can see the description as "Awarded 33 times.", but in the mobile-web view it is displaying as "33 users earned this badge."

**Desktop view:**

> [image: desktop view]

**Mobile-web view:**

> [image: mobile-web view]

Actually the Socratic badge has been awarded to only 25 users, with two users earning it three times and four users earning it twice.

```
+------------------------------+-------+
|           UserName           | Count |
+------------------------------+-------+
| αλεχολυτ                     |     3 |
| Shadow The Burning Wizard    |     3 |
| Arulkumar                    |     2 |
| Glorfindel                   |     2 |
| Disappointed in SE           |     2 |
| kiamlaluno                   |     2 |
| Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog |     1 |
| Martin                       |     1 |
| iBug says Reinstate Monica   |     1 |
| Patrick Hofman               |     1 |
| Shog9♦                       |     1 |
| Monica Cellio                |     1 |
| Undo - Reinstate Monica      |     1 |
| Grace Note♦                  |     1 |
| Michael Mrozek               |     1 |
| animuson♦                    |     1 |
| Andrew Grimm                 |     1 |
| Manishearth                  |     1 |
| Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' |     1 |
| Rosinante                    |     1 |
| Pekka supports GoFundMonica  |     1 |
| Pops                         |     1 |
| waffles                      |     1 |
| badp                         |     1 |
| Lance Roberts                |     1 |
+------------------------------+-------+
```

So technically "33 users earned this badge." in the mobile-web view is wrong. Can this be corrected?